# Opposite of 'damned with faint praise'?

Tags: idiom-requests

Is there an opposite of 'damned with faint praise'?

Meaning to subtly endorse something by making overly mild criticism.

Comment: "overly mild " - is that an oxymoron?

Comment: Interesting... Something like a girlfriend complaining that her boyfriend is too reliable? I'm trying to wrap my brain around this one. :)

Comment: The phrase *"not bad*" comes to mind.

Comment: I have used "praised with faint damn" on occasion.

Comment: The recent neologism, about oneself, is the awful sounding '[humblebrag](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/humblebrag)'

Answer (score 5):

*Praised with faint damns* is the usual way to oppose it. The construction is amenable, anyway.

Comment: May I add a cite,  (what I consider to be) a canonical example of the phrase's usage?  It would be a large edit, and I don't want to presume.

Comment: I could go along with this even if I've yet to see someone else use this. It invokes the original idiom and should be clear to everyone who's familiar with the original idiom.

Comment: I hear it reasonably often, usually with a faintly humorous tinge to it.

Answer (score 1):

In sales, such a tactic is called ***negative selling***, ***negative reverse selling*** or ***reverse selling***. You can read about it [here](http://activerain.com/blogsview/1335858/reverse-negative-selling--------what-do-you-think-) and [here](http://sacredappetite.com/2009/05/how-to-use-negative-reverse-selling-at-the-dinner-table/)

> "I know it's a really big investment, so you shouldn't feel pressured to pick up these widgets just because everyone else is."

or, if you are trying to convince your kid to eat her vegetables:

> "Yeah, I know it tastes bad, it's an adult taste."

Comment: Cool, learned a new phrase. But I don't think it'll be clear what I mean colloquially if I said, oh she's not *really hated, she was negatively sold.

Comment: @Rathony OP wants a term/idiom for the practice of intentionally undercutting the worth of something for the purpose of uplifting it in the eyes of the listener.  Negative selling, saying something bad about the product, uplifts the value of the product (or the company/person behind the product) by giving the listener feigned objectivity.  Although technical, it is on point.  Your comment is another example of how you're a pedant-ass.

Comment: @Rathony  lol my answer fits well with _(subtly) praise (elevate) with feigned damns_. Yet you downvote my answer and endorse the other.

Comment: @Rathony It's not possible to endorse something by criticising it, but it is possible to convince someone something is worthwhile by criticising it.  My answer fits into what the OP was most likely asking for.  For instance,  "I wasn't trying to put you down man, I was trying to negative sell you to the management."

Answer (score 1):

How about:  "Elevated with weak censure."

(I came up with it while trying to explain the unintended consequence of a poorly executed political satire.  I came here looking for something better.)

Answer (score -1):

In religious context, ressurection is the opposite of damnation.

Exalted is another word that you could use; however, I cannot think of a word that means exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Actually salvation is the opposite of damnation in a religious context.

Comment: I meant this is the context rising from the dead into the heavens as opposed to being dammed, which has been associated with receding down into the earth into the pits of hell.

Comment: No, that's salvation. Resurrection is the opposite of *death*. But this doesn't have much to do with *damning with faint praise,* as that doesn't involve Hell.