# Opposite of 'damned with faint praise' (2nd variety)?

Tags: idiom-requests

Is there a commonly used term for what I would call "Damned with excessive praise"?

The idea I'm referring to is when a speaker uses exaggerated praise in a sarcastic way to disparage an idea or a speaker. I noticed an example in a book recently, but I can't seem to find an exact quote now. The example went something like "John Doe, quite clearly the greatest mind of the past 1000 years, recently proposed the following dazzling idea ...".

Any suggestions?

Note that I added "(2nd variety)" to the question title, since there is already a question with [the same name but a different idea](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299624/opposite-of-damned-with-faint-praise) - asking about "praised with mild criticism", where the best idiom provided was "praised with faint damns".

Comment: I always say "praised with faint damn."

Comment: I didn’t think the president’s name was John.

Answer (score 2):

I think that would fall under ***sarcasm*** which the Oxford Dictionaries defines as:

> ***[sarcasm](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sarcasm)***
>
> **NOUN**
>
> *[mass noun]*
>
> The use of irony to mock or convey contempt.
>
> *‘she didn't like the note of sarcasm in his voice’*

If you really wanted to specify the notion of praise, I would call it a *sarcastic compliment*.

Comment: Dorothy L Sayers mentions "praising with faint damns" in one of her Lord Peter Wimsey mystery novels.  (I think it was *Murder Must Advertise*.)

Comment: Thanks, but please note that I already used the word "sarcastic" in the question. I was hoping to find a more specific term for this particular use of sarcasm.