# Phrase for jokingly pretending that someone's good point is a flaw?

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there a phrase for complimenting someone by jokingly pretending that their good point is a flaw? Let me give an example, précised from a recent WhatsApp conversation:

A: That bike ride was way too windy.
B: Well your problem is that you're too light. You're at risk of being blown away in anything more than a gentle breeze.
C: Yes, you should eat more pies.

Of course B and C are really complimenting A's lack of weight relative to their own.

It's something like the opposite of a *backhanded compliment* (in which an insult is disguised as a compliment), so I wondered about *backhanded insult*, but (a) that phrase doesn't seem to be widely used; (b) it doesn't seem to be used consistently, sometimes being a synonym for backhanded compliment (perhaps by people who are confused about the meaning of the latter?); and (c) such examples as there are seem to be more insulting than my example. (Refs: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Backhanded%20Insult, https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-a-backhanded-compliment-and-a-backhanded-insult).

I also wondered about something derived from *damned with faint praise*, as in this question: [Opposite of 'damned with faint praise'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299624/opposite-of-damned-with-faint-praise). Again it's not quite right though: "praised with faint damnation" would mean that you're finding a genuine but tiny flaw, with the implication that that's the worst you can find to say; in my example the flaw is not genuine, it's exactly their good point that is being humourously presented as a flaw.

So does anyone have a better way to describe this device?

Comment: I think something like this has been posted here before, _pero tengo hueva_...

Comment: It’s a form of **teasing**. Sometimes, after making a statement like this, the teaser will apologize or lighten the tone with a statement like “Y’know I’m just pullin’ your chain, right?”. https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+someone%27s+chain

Comment: I see no complimenting in the initial remark but rather a matter of fact  assertion to the effect that relatively light weight is a handicap against strong wind; after all, light weight is not necessarily a question of dieting, and often it is just simply the dominant characteristic associated with a particular inherited body shape, in particular in the case of gender difference. In the second sentence I see a somewhat  exaggerated truth that could aim at emphasizing what is, again, a real possibility; said with a sincerely friendly smile, that should not be taken amiss (1/3)

Comment: by the interlocutor; after all it is a rather amusing thing to imagine ourselves being  blown away in a gust of wind and we all know that there is always a strong enough wind that will achieve that, whatever our body mass (that is, if we are sentient enough); I can hardly acknowledge any teasing in that case. Said seriously, that might leave the interlocutor rather perplex as to what the exaggeration means, and it could be an expression of contempt; but one must always be sure before concluding to anything in such situations. I think however   (2/3)

Comment: that user Benjamin Harman, whose point of view does have a real connection to reality, is too uncompromising and that, perhaps, his outlook on life in this particular context could be incomplete. I'll put it to him in support of what I advance that it is not uncommon  that amusing remarks of that sort are made by people with  such would-be deficiencies (for short and for want of a better term) as applied to their own person, for the amusement of all.  (3/3)

Comment: Guys, this convo is not profitable.